# using statement changing the return value

Tags: c#, using-statement

I have the following code that works as expected. Below that I thought I would add some using statements to make sure everything is disposed of correctly but when i do I get a No data received error page in chrome.  If this is because the using statement is disposing(only possibility I could think of...) of the webresponse object how can I return the stream and dispose of webresponse properly?  The stream is being returned when a call is being made to a web service this code is a apart of, this results in a file uploading to the client.  At least it works in the first example given.

```
public Stream test(string fileName)  //this works fine
{
    WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    context.OutgoingResponse.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = string.Format("filename= {0}", fileName);
    return stream;
}

public Stream test(string fileName)///gives No data recieved error in chrome
{
    WebResponse webResponse;
    using(webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        context.OutgoingResponse.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = string.Format("filename= {0}", fileName);
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you doing with the stream?

Comment: Added that information to end of question.

Comment: @X-li Thanks for improving posts. But please make only substantial edits. At least 3 people need to review your changes before they get approved. That takes time of the reviewers. Make it worth it and leave minor edits to the users having enough rep to edit without needing approval. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea in what kind of context you are running this code and what you do with that stream but here is my reasoning.

`WebResponse` is `IDisposable` which means that when you put it into a `using` statement, it will get disposed at the end of the scope.

1. You are disposing the WebResponse instance: `webResponse`.
2. `webResponse` disposes all `IDisposable`s of its own when it gets disposed.
3. `webResponse` disposes the response stream: `stream`.
4. Your `test` function returns `stream`.
5. `stream` is unusable because it had been disposed.
6. Problem!

**Edit:**

Answer to your comment:

That's how `IDisposable` objects are expected to work as defined in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx

Here is a typical `IDisposable` class implementation:

```
// ExampleClass is similar to WebResponse
public class ExampleClass: IDisposable
{
    private IDisposable somethingDisposable;
    private bool disposed = false;

    public ExampleClass() 
    {
        somethingDisposable = new ...
        ...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Check to see if Dispose has already been called. 
        if(!this.disposed)
        {
            if(disposing)
            {
                // Your stream is disposed similar to
                // what happens here:
                // IDisposable objects dispose all managed/unmanaged 
                // resources that they have in their Dispose function.

                somethingDisposable.Dispose();
            }

            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    // This is similar to WebResponse.GetResponseStream
    public IDisposable GetSomethingDisposable() 
    {
        return somethingDisposable;
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    IDisposable d;
    using(var e = new ExampleClass()) {
        d = e.GetSomethingDisposable();
    }
    // here both e and d are disposed.
}
```

Comment: I thought that, but why would it dispose of the variable containing the data? It would only dispose of the objects that where coming straight off the disposing object, surely?

Comment: @No1_Melman the stream doesn't contain the data - it's a mechanism to get the data from the source.  When the stream is disposed so is your ability to get to the data.  You need to either not dispose of the request until it's done or not return a stream (return the binary data instead).

Comment: +1. @No1_Melman - `Dispose` disposes object and whatever that object "owns" - i.e. in your case WebRespose owns headers, response stream. Some objects (like headers collection) can be used past "disposed" state (or have no specific "disposed" state at all and no corresponding `Dispose`), others (like most `Steam`-derived objects) are completely useless after disposing as you just found out. Other common case is `Writer` objects disposing its inner streams.

Comment: @DStanley or really anyone...How can I get the binary data?

Comment: @Timigen Use the various `Read` of `Copy` functions of `Stream`.

Answer (score 1):

When you clean up the resources for the response you've cleaned up the resources that the `Stream` you're passing out needs to yield its data, thus preventing it from being used any further.

You need to dispose of the resource *after you are done using that stream*.